# Prevent caching index.html file using spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring-boot and want to prevent caching of index.html but cache all other resources, I have put the resource files on my classpath and prevented caching using the following.

Currently I am doing the following which is caching all files.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final int SEVEN_DAYS_IN_SECONDS = 604800;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:frontend/dist/")
                .setCachePeriod(SEVEN_DAYS_IN_SECONDS);
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

}
```

The index.html file is located at frontend/dist/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it this way:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

   registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:frontend/dist/index.html")
            .setCachePeriod(0);

   registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:frontend/dist/assets")
            .setCachePeriod(SEVEN_DAYS_IN_SECONDS);

    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
}
```

Comment: You can use `CacheControl.maxAge()` rather than creating constants manually.

Answer (score 2):

Using spring boot 2.1.1 and additionally spring security 5.1.1.

**1. For resources using resourcehandler in code (UNTESTED):**

You can add customized extensions of resources this way.

```
registry.addResourceHandler
```

Is for adding the uri path where to get the resource/s

```
.addResourceLocations
```

Is for setting the location in the filesystem where the resources are located(
given is a relative with classpath

```
.setCacheControl
.setCachePeriod
```

Is for setting the cache headers (self explanatory.)

Resourcechain and resolver are optional (in this case exactly as the default values.)

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

private static final int SEVEN_DAYS_IN_SECONDS = 604800;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
    registry.setOrder(1).addResourceHandler("/index.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:frontend/dist/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .mustRevalidate())
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noStore())
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());

    registry.setOrder(0).addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:frontend/dist/")
            .setCachePeriod(SEVEN_DAYS_IN_SECONDS)
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
}
```

**2. At controller level**

(yourwebsite.com/index.html)

```
@GetMapping("/index.html")
public void getIndex(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL,
             "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MappedInterceptor` and `WebContentInterceptor` as more flexible solution of configuring `Cache-Control` headers to different static resources.

```
    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor cacheControlInterceptor() {
        WebContentInterceptor webContentInterceptor = new WebContentInterceptor();
        webContentInterceptor.setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS).cachePublic());
        webContentInterceptor.addCacheMapping(CacheControl.noStore().mustRevalidate(), "/index.html");
        // if using Spring Security CacheControlHeadersWriter:
        // webContentInterceptor.addCacheMapping(CacheControl.empty(), "/", "/index.html");
        return new MappedInterceptor(null, webContentInterceptor);
    }
```

Why is bean needed? Please see [Note](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addInterceptors-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry-)

See also: [SPR-10655](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10655) and [SPR-13780](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13780) (it can be strange because even Spring Security CacheControlHeadersWriter use chain of 4 directives such as "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate")

Comment: This does not work for me as the ResourceHttpRequestHandler is overwriting the Cache Headers written by cacheControllInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

Solution by jax is fine but be aware not to `extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport` otherwise it does not wor and with spring boot you can extend the config and so you don't need the second part. This peace of code works:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class SinglePageApplicationResourceHandler implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/index.html")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

And you usually need to extend it with a catch all mapping like this:

```
@Controller
public class SinglePageApplicationController {

  @RequestMapping("/**/{path:[^.]*}")
  public String redirect() {
    return "forward:/index.html";
  }
}
```